# How to change repository an existing working copy points to without discarding existing changes?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm working on a SVN repository and made changes from it. However, the people I'm working with decided to set up a new SVN repository with a different URL and told me not to commit any new changes to the old repository. I tried to relocate the working copy but it failed. I want to merge my changes in the new repo without commiting to the old repo or doing the entire merge manually. How can I do that? I'm using TortoiseSVN.

Comment: How did the relocate fail?

Comment: The working copy and the new repo have different uuid. Should I turn "Include externals" on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the UUID has changed, you can't use `svn relocate`. The safest thing to do is to check out a fresh working copy, then copy your changes over to it and commit them. Otherwise, see [these search results](https://www.google.com/search?&q=svn+relocate+uuid&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#rls=en&q=svn+relocate+uuid) for some ideas about how to do it. Warning: it involves mucking with the contents of your `.svn` directory, which is not supported/recommended.

It would have been easier on everyone if the people moving your repository had kept the same UUID when they did it.

Comment: I ended up copying my changes into a new working copy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

svn diff > QQQ.txt

then

patch -p0 < QQQ.txt

or

svn patch QQQ.txt